# How to count occurrences from two lists of words to determine language in use?

Tags: php, search, substring, find-occurrences

I want to find out the language used from a web page. Here I guess based on some of the words that come in the keyword list.

This script I get from http://www.kangsigit.com/2017/08/php.deteksi-bahasa.html

How this code works is just matching words to the `"INDONESIAN and ENGLISH"` keyword list. If one of your keywords comes in, then that's the language detected.

**The code:-**

```
$tulisan = "Hari ini saya dapat senyum oleh suatu hal";
 function Bahasa($tulisan, $terjemahkan) {
      $bahasa_pilihan = array('INDONESIAN','ENGLISH');
      $katakunci['INDONESIAN'] = array ('cinta', 'marah', 'sayang', 'benci', 'senyum', 'peluk');
      $katakunci['ENGLISH'] = array ('the', 'and', 'have', 'for', 'with', 'you');
      $tulisan = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", ' ', $tulisan);
      foreach ($bahasa_pilihan as $bahasa) {
        $kalkulasi[$bahasa]=0;
      }
      for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        foreach ($bahasa_pilihan as $bahasa) {
          $kalkulasi[$bahasa] = $kalkulasi[$bahasa] +

            substr_count($tulisan, ' ' .$katakunci[$bahasa][$i] . ' ');;
        }
      }
      $max = max($kalkulasi);
      $maxs = array_keys($kalkulasi, $max);
      if (count($maxs) == 1) {
        $pemenang = $maxs[0];
        $pertamax = 0;
        foreach ($bahasa_pilihan as $bahasa) {
          if ($bahasa <> $pemenang) {
            if ($kalkulasi[$bahasa]>$pertamax) {
              $pertamax = $kalkulasi[$bahasa];
            }
          }
        }
        if (($pertamax / $max) < 0.1) {
          return $pemenang;
        }
      }
      return $terjemahkan;
    }
 echo Bahasa($tulisan, $terjemahkan);
```

But there is a problem here.
If the keyword `"INDONESIAN and ENGLISH"` enters all, then the script becomes error.

An example is changed like this:

```
$tulisan = "Hari ini saya dapat senyum oleh suatu hal, you know?";
```

The two words `"senyum"`, and `"you"` come from different keywords. Generate error.

Is there a way to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

If in Indonesian there are 2 words, and English is only one word, then the Indonesian language is the winner. But the code above does not work as I expected.

**For example:**

```
$tulisan = "Hari ini saya cinta dan dapat senyum oleh suatu hal, you know?";
```

There are two words from the Indonesian language, namely (`cinta` and `senyum`).

There is one word from English, that is (`you`).

So it should be, the detected language is `INDONESIA`.

Comment: I'd personally recommend **mapping** each word to its equivalent value in an associative array, rather than using two independent arrays and trying to calculate various offsets.

Comment: hello ALL.. I have updated my question. Please read back. Thanks

Comment: @mickmackusa  i have added that solution in my answer note section too. You can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it like below:-

```
<?php

$tulisan = "Hari ini saya dapat senyum oleh suatu hal";

function Bahasa($tulisan) {
  $bahasa_pilihan = array('INDONESIAN','ENGLISH');
  $katakunci['INDONESIAN'] = array ('cinta', 'marah', 'sayang', 'benci', 'senyum', 'peluk');
  $katakunci['ENGLISH'] = array ('the', 'and', 'have', 'for', 'with', 'you');

  $exploded_string = explode(' ',$tulisan);
  $indonasian_counter = 0;
  $english_counter = 0;

  foreach($exploded_string as $string){
     if(in_array($string, $katakunci['INDONESIAN'])){
       $indonasian_counter +=1;
     }
      if(in_array($string, $katakunci['ENGLISH'])){
       $english_counter +=1;
     }
  }
  if($indonasian_counter >$english_counter){
    echo "given string have more Indonesian words";echo PHP_EOL;
  }
  if($english_counter > $indonasian_counter){
    echo "given string have more English words";echo PHP_EOL;
  }
  if($english_counter == $indonasian_counter){
    echo "given string have a tie between Languages";echo PHP_EOL;
  }    

}

Bahasa($tulisan);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/842143  ***OR***  https://eval.in/842145  ***(case-insensitive)***

***Note:-*** if you want to make it ***case-insensitive search*** then do:-

```
if(in_array(strtolower($string), array_map("strtolower",$katakunci['INDONESIAN']))){
```

Ans same for `English`:-

```
if(in_array(strtolower($string), array_map("strtolower",$katakunci['ENGLISH']))){
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Oh yes,, my test adds `$tulisan = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", ' ', $tulisan);` cool as well ..

Comment: Why did you ask for an upvote?  We aren't meant to do that, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimized method that maintains your search words from each language as an array.

It uses the power of `preg_match_all()` with a pattern including word boundaries, alternatives, and a case-insensitive flag.

This method is very well suited for your case because you will not need to prepare your string using `preg_replace()` or `strtolower()`.

The condition statement is built for speed in that if the search for English matches results in `0`, then the search for Indonesian matches is never called.  In other words, when there are no English words, there are only two function calls before the return (specifically: `preg_match_all()` once and `implode()` once).  When there are 1 or more English words in `$tulisan` the same two functions are called just one more time each.

**`preg_match_all()` is the perfect function** for this task because it removes the need for any looping, it can be set to case-insensitive, and it returns the number of matches that it finds.

```
function Bahasa($tulisan){
    $katakunci['INDONESIAN'] = array ('cinta', 'marah', 'sayang', 'benci', 'senyum', 'peluk');
    $katakunci['ENGLISH'] = array ('the', 'and', 'have', 'for', 'with', 'you');
    if(($eng=preg_match_all('/\b(?:'.implode('|',$katakunci['ENGLISH']).')\b/i',$tulisan)) && $eng>preg_match_all('/\b(?:'.implode('|',$katakunci['INDONESIAN']).')\b/i',$tulisan)){
        return 'English';  // if English > 0 AND English is greater than Indonesian
    }else{
        return "Indonesian";  // if English == 0 OR Indonesian >= English
    }
}
```

These are some calls and outputs: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1881a6155531be72cf6555ec30cb108d2b8eff1))

```
$tulisan = "Hari ini saya dapat senyum oleh suatu hal, you know?";
echo Bahasa($tulisan);  // Indonesian  (because senyum x1, you x1

$tulisan = "Hari ini saya dapat senyum oleh suatu hal?";
echo Bahasa($tulisan);  // Indonesian  (because no English)

$tulisan = "You know, hari ini saya dapat senyum oleh suatu hal, you know?";
echo Bahasa($tulisan);  // English  (because senyum x1, you x2)
```

> Now if you are happy/comfortable dealing directly with the pattern expression, you can improve efficiency and brevity like this:
>
> ```
> function Bahasa($tulisan){
>     if(($eng=preg_match_all('/\b(?:the|and|have|for|with|you)\b/i',$tulisan)) && $eng>preg_match_all('/\b(?:cinta|marah|sayang|benci|senyum|peluk)\b/i',$tulisan)){
>         return 'English';  // if English > 0 AND English is greater than Indonesian
>     }else{
>         return "Indonesian";  // if English == 0 OR Indonesian >= English
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @GeeJhon Please have another look at my answer.  I have taken the time to optimize my answer and explain my method.